# ssr html markup is not generating in nextjs app on vercel in production but works in local dev environment

Tags: next.js, client, server-side-rendering

My website is hosted on vercel and If I access this page - https://www.softpost.org/nextjs13, you will see that in the network tab, there is no html data sent by the server. Entire content is being generated at client side after hydration.

But same code works in local dev environment and full html page is sent by the server as seen in response. So I was wondering why this might be happening?

I inspected response sent by server in prod and dev. I was expecting same SSR responses in both cases. But in case of prod, no ssr is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to "entire page deopted to client side rendering" which in turn is caused by calling useSearchParams function in a component and not wrapping that component by suspense boundry.